# Different query after nhibernate 5 (using oracle)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

After upgrading from 4.1 to 5.2, nhibernate is creating a query a little different, putting an "OR" where it is not welcome.

### 4.1

```
...,
...,   
(select cast(count(guia5_.ID) as NUMBER(10, 0))
  from SAM_GUIA guia5_

 where guia5_.PEGID = peg1_.ID                        <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

) as col_41_0_,
```

### 5.x

```
...,
...,   
(select cast(count(guia5_.ID) as NUMBER(10, 0))
   from SAM_GUIA guia5_

  where guia5_.PEGID = peg1_.ID                        <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
     or (guia5_.PEGID is null)                         <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    and (peg1_.ID is null)                             <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

) as col_41_0_,
```

The linq query related is:

```
...,
...,
RecordCount = (from c in repositoryGuia.All()
           where c.PegId == b.Id
           select c.Id
           ).Count(),
```

More information about mapping:

- c.PegId:  int?
- b.Id: int

Using NHibernate 5.2.6 and Fluent 2.1.2.

Why version 5 is translating to a different SQL statement?

Comment: If you change the  query to `where c.PegId.Value == b.id` does it change the query to not use the `or`? I ask this because back when I worked in a project that used EF some querys would perform null checks when not using `.Value` in Linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known 5.x issue [GH-1860](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1860). Details when and why behavior is changed explained [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1860#issuecomment-430553642).
AFAIK there is no workaround for LINQ so you have to use hql/QueryOver if it's a showstopper for you.

But there is an open pull request [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/1996) that should fix this behavior. So maybe in 5.3 it will be fixed.